# What does `import ...` mean in Python 3?

Tags: python

From a quick search, I know that one dot means in the current directory, two dots mean in the parent directory, and three dots mean in the grandparent directory, but these examples are usually written as `from .. import PackageName`

What if the code was just `import ...`? Does this import every file in the grandparent directory? (The reason why I ask is that I'm working with some files that has this import statement at the top, but there is nothing in the grandparent directory to import).

Comment: I don't think it allows you to use ```...``` It should throw an error...

Answer (score 3):

The dots mimic the Unix file system that `.` refers to the current directory and `..` refers to the parent. `...` has no such conventional meaning. In Python, however, `...` is the literal for the singleton value of the `ellipsis` class:

```
>>> type(...)
<class 'ellipsis'>
```

As such, `import ...` would be a syntax error, as `...` is not a valid module name.

Comment: I don't think `ellipsis` is relevant to the question. The name in an `import` statement is never meant as a variable name and the OP apparently knows it already. The question is really about why `from ... import PackageName` is allowed while `import ...` isn't.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that `from ... import <stuff>` is, indeed legal.

Answer (score 0):

What if the code was just import ...?

as @chepner said, ... means <class 'ellipsis'>, but you can't import it.

in PyCharm "import ..." means it is a folded code block：

[image]

the full code is like this（click the “+” button）：

[image]

Maybe other IDEs are like this too.

Answer (score 0):

The ... states for the relative import from "grandparent" directory.
It follows the convention, that '.' is a current directory, '..' is a parent directory and so on.

For example, I have created three directories a, b, c inside each other and following files in them:

```
~/example % cat run.py
from a.b.c import c_fun


def main():
    c_fun()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
~/example % cat a/__init__.py

~/example % cat a/b/__init__.py
from .lib import fun

~/example % cat a/b/lib.py
def fun():
    print('Hello')

~/example % cat a/b/c/__init__.py
from .src import c_fun

~/example % cat a/b/c/src.py
from ... import b


def c_fun():
    b.fun()

~/example %
```

So running `run.py` gives

```
~/example % python3 run.py
Hello
```